In ggplot2 with cowplot and plot_grid, How Increase Vertical Height for Individual Plots Where ncol = 1?
In ggplot2 with cowplot and plot_grid, how can the vertical height for each individual plots be increased when ncol = 1?
With parm_ncol = 1, this code:
grid_plot <- plot_grid(plotlist = list_of_plots_for_grid_plot,
                       ncol = parm_ncol,
                       scale = 1)

Generates a grid plot with each row "smushed."

Tried:

rel_widths and/or rel_heights; neither/both do not effect the outcome,

greedy; no effect,

scale (1, 1.2, 5): Enlarges the plot_grid but does not unsmush the rows.


Seeking a way(s) to force cowplot/plot_grid to increase the row height by at least a factor of 4.
Suggestions?

How are you saving your grid_plot? If you use e.g. ggsave() you can specify your width and height in 'units', i.e. if you use ggsave(plot = grid_plot, filename = "example.png", width = 10, height = 40, units = "cm") do you get a less 'smushed' plot?

Another option is to specify the aspect ratio of each plot that goes into your plot_list. Also, the {patchwork} package may do a better job of assembling the plots.

@jared_mamrot, many thanks for your suggestion! It worked. To my surprise, it was ggsave that appears to be doing the 'smushing'; not grid_plot. With your help, I now have a set of properly rendered Lattice plots.

Glad you solved your problem @PlaneWryter :)

Here are a couple of alternative approaches that use facet_wrap() or the patchwork package. In either option, you can resize the plot by selecting Export-Save as Image and then changing the width and height values. Saving the figure this way can be a bit iterative but some prefer it over using ggsave().
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

# Option 1: Facet wrap
diamonds %>%
  filter(cut %in% c('Fair','Good','Very Good')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = carat, y = price)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~cut, ncol = 1)



# Option 2: Using the patchwork package
p1 <- diamonds %>%
  filter(cut == 'Fair') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = carat, y = price)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = 'Cut: Fair') +
  theme_bw()

p2 <- diamonds %>%
  filter(cut == 'Good') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = carat, y = price)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = 'Cut: Good') +
  theme_bw()

p3 <- diamonds %>%
  filter(cut == 'Very Good') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = carat, y = price)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = 'Cut: Very Good') +
  theme_bw()

p1 + p2 + p3 + plot_layout(ncol = 1)


Created on 2024-05-16 with reprex v2.1.0
